# What is Callback URL?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am creating a new application in Twitter [Twitter API](https://apps.twitter.com/app/new)

It is asking for CallBack Url what is main use of callback URL and its mandatory to use callback url as for me i am creating new app to get Access-Token so that i can use this to work with Twitter4j?

[Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) is used to integration Twitter API with Java.

I want following from this API

1. Login in my website through Twitter Like Stackverflow given login with OPENID
2. User Information
3. Number of follower
4. All Tweets of any account
5. Search on some Keyword basis

If i will not give Callback Url everything will work fine?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the API is for you  to make requests to Twitter.

Twitter needs  to  know where to send the results of your request.

Otherwise how will you know what happened?  This is  how you get the token to use it in your code.

Comment: Callback URL  to send token back?